# I would like to create a script for collecting multiple subscription requests and generating an e-mail notification

Tags: email, notifications, dotnetnuke, subscription

We have an existing website that is built on DNN.  I would like to add a script to an existing page that collects a user's request for to subscribe to various e-mails we publish and then to  generate an e-mail that idenfies those requested newsletter subscription titles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Data springs has some good subscription tools available, check out their suite of modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just collect names and email addresses with a request, the DNN Form and List module will work just fine.

If you just want a "subscribe to our newsletter" type of link on your page, you could couple that with a modal popup that shows the form when the link is clicked(Here is an excellent tutorial:  http://www.dnncreative.com/Tutorials/DNNTutorialsforAdministrators/EasilycreatePopupsusingdnnModalshow/tabid/679/Default.aspx that will show you how to do it.)